# React-select defaultValue from API request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-select

I want to set default value for react-select when I open particular request which I get from API. `Cities` options for my select are too from API and they work well.

```
const [request, setRequest] = useState<IRequest>();
const [cities, setCities] = useState<ICity[]>([]);
const [defaultCity, setDefaultCity] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get<IRequest>('/api/requests/' + id)
        .then((res) => {
            setRequest(res.data)
            setDefaultCity({ value: res.data.city.code, label: res.data.city.name })
        })
    axios.get<ICity[]>('/api/cities')
        .then(res => setCities(res.data))
}, [])
```

Here is my select

```
<Select
    placeholder='City'
    defaultValue={defaultCity}
    options={
       cities.map(city => (
           { value: city.code, label: city.name }
       ))
    }
/>
```

If I console.log when submitting form `defaultCity` is what I want (because of asynchronous I guess).

`Request` object looks like this

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "status": {
            "code": "DRAFT"
        },
        "city": {
            "code": "MSC",
            "name": "Moscow"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar kind of issue. An elegant way to solve it to set option value prior.

```
<option value={defaultCity.value && ''}>{defaultCity?.label}</option>
```